# How can I install 32 bit pyq on Mac OS 64 bit, for python 3.6-32

Tags: python, kdb, pyq

I have 32 bit kdb on my Mac OS, and want to use pyq with Python3.6 32 bit version.
Currently, I have it working perfectly for  32 bit Python2.7 after installing it as below.

```
./python2.7-32 pip install -i https://pyq.enlnt.com --no-binary pyq pyq
```

Now I need to use with Python3.6 and try similarly to install the 32 bit via:

```
 ./python3.6-32 pip install -i https://pyq.enlnt.com --no-binary pyq pyq
```

It does install it but when I try to run in after something happens and It gives me an error:

```
~$:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin> ./pyq
'2017.05.02T21:14:50.022 dlopen(libpython3.6m.dylib, 10): image not found
@
"q"
"r:py[`pyq^`$getenv`PYTHONEXECUTABLE;args;lib]"
```

Comment: Why? This is going to be nothing but trouble. macOS has gone 64-bit only and has been that way for years now. All the 32-bit libraries have been thrown out. If you really need a 32-bit environment, run it in a VM.

Comment: Point taken. I will use 2.7 for now then. Its for learning purposes anyway.

Comment: I am not sure what `./python3.6-32` is in your command.  Is this your custom built python executable?  In this case you should probably specify `-mpip`, not just `pip` on the command line.

We recommend using universal builds from brew:
`brew install sashkab/python/python36 --universal`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the error message

```
dlopen(libpython3.6m.dylib, 10): image not found
```

it looks like you've built a statically linked python and used the `--with-pymalloc` config option.  Please make sure that you configure your python with `--enable-shared`.  Better yet, use a universal built from brew:

```
brew install sashkab/python/python36 --universal
```

Finally, if you are going to use multiple versions of python, consider using virtual environments.

For detailed instructions, see ["Installing PyQ on macOS"](https://pyq.enlnt.com/install/install.html#installing-pyq-on-macos).

Comment: There is now a [guide](https://pyq.enlnt.com/install/install.html#installing-pyq-on-macos) on how to install PyQ on macOS using Python included into the system, and brewed Python.